# aspnet core mvc SPA - oauth flow on the front or backend?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs, oauth, adfs3.0

I have a react SPA that is served via aspnet core MVC. The SPA interacts with 3rd party API's. The mvc back-end is only responsible for serving the initial app.

The oauth is being done against ADFS that does not support a client secret. It returns the auth code based on client id and a user sign-on. Then an additional request needs to be made to get the auth token.

I am trying to determine if there is any benefit to handling this scenario on the mvc backend rather than handling it on the front-end (seeing as the client secret is not supported with ADFS)

Comment: how would the front-end receive the token? a typical oauth flow requires a post url to receive the token

Comment: @azium - Once the token is received by the backend it could be persisted in a cookie for the browser to access ? The callback url would be the backend endpoint to receive the token.

Comment: that sounds right. but then you're using the backend and I'm not longer sure what the premise of your question is

Comment: @azium - Thanks for your responses, the premise of the question is - should the token request/redirect come from the SPA (i.e load the app then request credentials etc) or is there security benefit to doing this token request from the server side (MVC) if ADSF 3.0 only supports code authorization flow for public clients.